Bind mount two host directories to the same container directory without overriding its content, is it possible?
Is it possible to bind mount two host directories to the same container directory without overriding its content?
I need to maintain the sources from the first bind mount + new ones (from the second bind mount). I understand that files and dirs containing the same names can be overridden but what about the rest? Will Docker always override them no matter what?
See the following example:
# Dockerfile
FROM someimage

COPY app /app
COPY consumers/site1/theme /app/src/styles

# docker-compose.yml
services:
  base:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: "."
      dockerfile: local/Dockerfile.consumer
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/app/src
      - ./consumers/site1/theme:/app/src/styles

files from the 2nd bind mount in my docker-compose overrides everything under /app/src/styles... is there any way to achieve this? a workaround?

Mounting the same path twice is not allowed, except in the case of binding, which essentially cheats by mounting one folder into another path., imho.

Docker has no option for something like that, but outside of Docker (or maybe even inside, haven't tested it) you can use an overlayfs mount.
mount -t overlay overlay -o lowerdir=./app/src/styles,upperdir=./consumes/site1/theme,workdir=./styles_work ./styles

Then you can mount ./styles at the desired point.
    volumes:
      - ./app/src:/app/src
      - ./styles:/app/src/styles


Edit: Seems like you can even define that directly in the docker-compose.yml file
Excerpt from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58770954/212107 :
volumes:
  overlay3:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: overlay
      o: lowerdir=${PWD}/ro-data,upperdir=${PWD}/upper3,workdir=${PWD}/work3
      device: overlay

services:
  overlay3:
    image: busybox
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    container_name: cont3
    volumes:
    - overlay3:/data

